# Different results for different struts2 action suffixes

Tags: struts2, struts-action

I want Struts2 action to return different pages based on action suffix. I think it is possible to create a filter that wraps original request and changes URL the way that URL's with different suffixes will be mapped to different actions.

But this solution looks ugly and I'm curious is there any other way to do this.

Comment: The REST mapper does this. How to do it cleanly depends at what level you want to make the differentiation, whether it's app-wide or just across one or a few actions, etc., ranging from trivial to complex.

Comment: I don't understand the down/close vote, please explain.

Comment: Thank you Dave, I didn't used REST mapper before and I'll take a look on it. On the other side I am afraid that using it for such unrelevant objective is even worse than writing filter to wrap request :)

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you use it, I was suggesting you could see how it implements that functionality.

Comment: If I only needed that on few actions, I'd rather did some dirty workaround. But I need it to work application-wide. The same action name and method, but different views depending on action suffix. Thanks for directing me to the REST plugin.